# Gcp pubsub ordering key

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have started using gcp pubsub to publish messages in my application through Java client libraries. Though I have one question regarding ordering key type. In the PubSubMessage object, the setter for ordering key as input argument as String.. Is it possible to use ordering key as avro or other types? ( for data we can use string, json, avro etc )

Comment: The ordering key is always a string, the message data is in B64, encode whatever you want in the payload.

Comment: Thanks for the information. 
Can’t I have an object as avro and convert to ByteString and do pubsubmessage.setOrderingKeyBytes( byteString) ? This way I can use avro, json or normal string as key?

Comment: Hmm you could. I didn't find the max length but I'm sure there is a limit. However, I'm not sure to understand the use case...